# Using Your Own Text Editor On a Server

Tags: editor, hosting

Are there any hosting providers which allow you to use your own text editor to edit hosted files? At the moment, I'm using Namecheap and I can only edit hosted files through their code editor which means I need to edit the files locally and then upload them if I want to use my own text editor. I'd really like to develop a site directly on the server so skipping this step would save quite a bit of time.

Specifically, I'd like to use Sublime Text 2. Google didn't help so I'm hoping someone hear could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [EasyEditors](http://www.easyeditors.com/) might have what you need.  It appears that you can edit the files on their site.